# Cut, copy and paste excel

Tags: vba, excel

In VBA are you able to carry out a copy and paste straight after a cut and paste. I ask because If statement within a for loop that needs to cut a row of data and then copy the row directly underneath. When I run the code it performs that cut but never the copy. I looked into this online and the only thing I could come up with is clearing the clipboard. Sadly this not help :(.

Here is my code:

```
im r As Range
Dim i As Long, i2 As Long, i4 As Long
i = 2
i2 = 15
i3 = 70
i4 = 3
For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
v = r.Value
    If InStr(v, "ION") > 0 And InStr(v, "Dog") > 0 Then
        Range(Cells(r.Row, r.Column), Cells(r.Row, r.Column + 2)).Cut
        Range(Cells(i, 8), Cells(i, 10)).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Range(Cells(r.Row + 1, r.Column), Cells(r.Row + 1, r.Column + 2)).Copy
        Range(Cells(i4, 8), Cells(i4, 10)).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        i = i + 2
        i4 = i4 + 2
```

There is then more code using elseif's to search for other words but the code above is the code in question.

To reiterate, the cut/paste works. the copy/paste does not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really able to replicate the problem you're having, but you could try changing these three lines:

```
Range(Cells(r.Row + 1, r.Column), Cells(r.Row + 1, r.Column + 2)).Copy
Range(Cells(i4, 8), Cells(i4, 10)).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

To this:

```
Range(Cells(r.Row + 1, r.Column), Cells(r.Row + 1, r.Column + 2)).Copy _
    Range(Cells(i4, 8), Cells(i4, 10))
```

You can do the same thing with the `.Cut` method:, which would become:

```
Range(Cells(r.Row, r.Column), Cells(r.Row, r.Column + 2)).Cut _
    Range(Cells(i, 8), Cells(i, 10))
```

NB: It is rarely necessary to activate, `Select` or otherwise "click" the range objects that you need to work with.  Here is a great explanation:

[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Comment: Hi David, Thank you for you reply. That is a much tidier way of writing the code. The issue still persists tho. It's incredibly annoying =P

Comment: What happens when you step through the code? I am surprised if it fails to copy without raising an error of any sort.